# Unable to reach router using ethernet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

After trying Ubuntu 20.04.3 using Live boot I decided to completely switch from Windows.
However having installed Ubuntu I realized that the Ethernet connection to my router is not working anymore, please note that while Windows 10 was still installed and while using Live boot everything worked just fine.
Without setting a static IP address, I get the error `Activation of network connection failed.` When I have set a static IP and I ping my router I get the following output:

```
$ ping 192.168.178.1

PING 192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.61 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Between my router and my PC I have D-Link DGS-105 LAN switch sitting, which I assume is causing this problem.

Running the following commands I get this output:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 0c
       serial: b4:2e:99:19:41:be
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe600000-fe600fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: wlx503eaa82fc4f
       serial: 50:3e:aa:82:fc:4f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt76x0u driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.178.61 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
$ sudo resolvectl status

Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 3 (wlx503eaa82fc4f)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1
          DNS Domain: ~.           
                      fritz.box    

Link 2 (enp4s0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
```

```
$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:19:41:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.61/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5254:585a:126:51dc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlx503eaa82fc4f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:82:fc:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.61/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx503eaa82fc4f
       valid_lft 863972sec preferred_lft 863972sec
    inet6 fe80::75d1:bc59:1b3c:c6e2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ ip r

default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp4s0 proto static metric 100 
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlx503eaa82fc4f proto dhcp metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp4s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.61 metric 100 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlx503eaa82fc4f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.61 metric 600
```

For whatever reason it just seems to work now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add in your question the output of the commands `ip a` `ip r`

Comment: Does it work if you bypass the D-Link DGS-105 LAN switch and connect directly to your router?

Comment: I don't have a long enough cable at hand to try that.

Comment: I have now added output for `ip a` and `ip r`

Comment: Your network configuration is invalid: subnets for ethernet and wifi overlaps. Can you reconfigure your wifi subnet?